# Trying to use QGIS to make AK election results maps

Tags: qgis

I have QGIS.

I have a current shapefile of the political boundaries of Alaska's boroughs and census areas, acquired from the state's GIS engineers.

I have a PostgreSQL DB of AK election results going back to 1996 that I have beaten until it produces results by borough and census area.

All I want to do is make pretty little results maps that paint the political subdivisions degrees of red and blue.

I have absolutely no idea where to start or where to look for guidance.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a "QGIS for Drooling Imbeciles" type of guide?

I had previously been using the MapViewer 7 and MapViewer 8 software, but this poses problems because the AK gsm sample files that come with the software are relentlessly inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone point me in the direction of a "QGIS for Drooling Imbeciles" type of guide?

The [QGIS Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/) seems to me the most appropriate introductory course.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I've found that I can get Golden MapViewer 8 to import the official state shape files and it should suffice for my needs.

I think I'll leave the realm of GIS to the people who actually have a modicum of spacial reasoning.